# Display date field labels within selectors

Tags: forms

Is there a way to move the labels of the day/month/year components inside the selectors (like Facebook has it on their registration page, see 'Birthday')? I have placeholders in all my text fields and it looks silly that the labels of date fields sit on top.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to keep the labels in the code and just add the placeholders/default values. I will then hide the labels with CSS.

Comment: Check this do you want same like this http://www.richtown.ae/?q=news

Comment: Yes, exactly! That's what I need.

Comment: Are you using views to show the date ? - i am using the exposed filter for that date.

Comment: No, it's just a date field on the user registration form.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've just quickly whipped up a `sandbox` module to modify date options array. And here's the code, hope this helps:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter()
 * @param array $form
 * @param array $form_state
 * @param string $form_id
 */
function sandbox_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'article_node_form') {
    // Only call after builder if we're using date_combo type which is 3 select fields
    if($form['field_date'][$form['field_date']['#language']][0]['#type'] == 'date_combo') {
      // Add our after build function
      $form['field_date'][$form['field_date']['#language']]['#after_build'][] = 'sandbox_field_date_after_build';
    }
  } 
}

/**
 * After build callback
 * @param array $element
 * @param array $form_state
 * @return array
 */
function sandbox_field_date_after_build($element, &$form_state) {
  // Loop through each delta if more than 1 value  
  foreach(element_children($element) as $delta) {
    // Loop through each granularity e.g. month, day, year, hour, minute, second
    foreach(element_children($element[$delta]['value']) as $key) {
      // #options not set means this type of granularity isn't set, so we skip
      if(isset($element[$delta]['value'][$key]['#options'])) {
        // If there's an empty value, change the option label to be '- [#title] -'
        if(isset($element[$delta]['value'][$key]['#options'][''])) {
          $element[$delta]['value'][$key]['#options'][''] = '- ' . $element[$delta]['value'][$key]['#title'] . ' -';
        }
        // Otherwise insert an empty value at beginning with label '- [#title] -'
        else {
          array_unshift($element[$delta]['value'][$key]['#options'], array('' => '- '. $element[$delta]['value'][$key]['#title'] . ' -'));
        }
        // Make the title invisible
        $element[$delta]['value'][$key]['#title_display'] = 'invisible';
      }
    }
  }

  return $element;
}
```

Which produces this result provided you have set "No default value" in the field instance setting:
[image]

Or you can always do it in the Advanced Settings of any date field.

Comment: I'd prefer to use a hook_form_alter() in a custom module. It shouldn't be complicated, I basically only need to set the default value but not count it as a submission value. But I'm not sure what the correct code for this would be.

Comment: Ah you said "text field" on your question but you really mean a "select field"? It should simply be a matter of prepending the label into the [`#options`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#options) array of the select field but set the return value of this option to an empty string, and that should work provided you have validation. Check this pseudo code: `$options = $form['field']['#options']; array_unshift($options, array('' => '- Year/Month/Day -'));`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need. Now I only need to find out how to alter the options of each component of the date field. $form['field_date']['und'][0]['value']['month']['#options'] doesn't work and Devel only shows me $form['field_date'] as type 'container', but not any sub-fields.

Comment: With regard to this, let me rephrase the question: How do I alter labels of the options of each of the date field select lists using hook_form_alter? I can't manage to access day/month/year separately.

Comment: @deinqwertz check my updated answer. Make sure you replace the $form_id check with the appropriate form_id you attaching this date field to.

Comment: Thanks a ton Beebee, I really appreciate your help. I'm afraid I just realized that labels can be moved 'inside' in the advanced settings of any date field. But I will most likely have to alter other components as well and I'm sure that your code will take me much further than I would've gotten by myself. Thank you so much!

Comment: No probs, it's not bad to crack a nut with a sledgehammer from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION 1:**

[Field placeholder](https://drupal.org/project/field_placeholder) adds a new option in field settings page to enter the placeholder value, which is included automatically when the widget is rendered.

**OPTION 2:**

This [Placeholder](https://drupal.org/project/placeholder) adds an extra FAPI attribute called '#placeholder' to textfield field elements. Often textfields should have some text in them like "Enter your text here" until the user clicks on (or tabs to) the element in question. At that point, the text should disappear and the user can enter his or her desired input.